# Residence permit for PhD student

Tags: visas, residency, czech-republic

I am not an EU citizen and currently I am doing a PhD in Switzerland possessing a B permit. I plan to terminate my contract and start PhD anew in Prague (3+ years). As I understood my B permit will be cancelled after termination of my PhD in Switzerland. Should I apply for a student visa, or directly apply for a long-term residence permit?

I am afraid to have a situation when I apply for a student permit, which by some random missing paper may be declined after 2 months and then a new application for long-term permit and/or student permit will result in an extra two month waiting time period, while I am allowed to stay in Czech republic only 90 days after arrival to the country. So, I can easily exceed that 3 month limit which will result in troubles.

Comment: Does the University in Prague not have an international office? If you are about to start there, they should be able to guide you through the process.

Comment: They said me that foreigners are taking care of coming by themselves and they don't know how it works.

Comment: Your question is better suited for expats and should soon be moved there but if there is no international office / secretary / colleagues or other staff to help you, this does not sound well for your institution IMHO.

Comment: Czech universities are extremely incompetent when it comes to visa questions. Move your question to Expats. SE and I'll answer it there.